# Alternatives to git filter-branch when purging a file from Git history?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

### Problem:

My team has two repos:

- A Bitbucket repo under active development, with a long commit history.
- A newer Github repo, under development by another team, which was created a month or so ago. Instead of forking the Bitbucket repo, for some reason *most of* the files from the Bitbucket repo were just copied and pushed to Github without the history from Bitbucket.

Until we retire Bitbucket, I want to be able to merge changes from Bitbucket over to Github. I've just finished doing this for the first time, so now the newer repo references the history of the older one.

The merge was successful on my machine, but I can't push it to Github because Github won't accept files > 100MB. The hilarious part is that I **don't need** the offending large file, and in fact *it was deleted* just after I merged `Bitbucket/develop` into `Github/develop`. Doesn't matter that it's no longer present in `HEAD`, it's in the history, so it gets pushed to Github.

### Solution?

- Purge the offending file from our Bitbucket repo's history (https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/).
- **Force push** all of the affected branches up to Bitbucket.
- Re-run the merge from Bitbucket to Github.

That is a pretty risky prospect. It'll mean everyone working on the old Bitbucket repo will need to push all of their work so far up to Bitbucket. I'll then do the purge. ​*Then once I'm done they will have to presumably delete their entire local clone, and re-get it*​. If they do any work in the meantime, they'll have to re-apply their commits on top of the new history.

### Question:

Are there any alternatives which I'm not considering?
Can I somehow purge the offending file from the newer repo's history while still maintaining the ability to merge from one repo to the other easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no

The reason is that each Git ref is identified by a SHA1 hash that is unique relative to (among other things) it's content.

To remove that file you will need to *rewrite* commits which will require a force-push.